# FullCalendar eventConstraint conflict with eventDataTransform function

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar where event data comes from a JSON feed.
The field names do not match fullCalendar field names so I use the eventDataTransform function like this:

```
eventDataTransform: function (eventData){
    var ro = new Object();
    ro.start = eventData.myStartField;
    ro.end = eventData.myEndField;
    ro.title = eventData.myTitleField;
    ro.sourceObject = eventData;
    console.log("converted event", ro);
    return ro;
}
```

I keep the original JSON object in a custom field 'sourceObject'.

This works perfect. No issues.
Until I add a constraint to fullCalendar:

```
eventConstraint: {start: "08:00:00", end: "16:00:00"}
```

From that moment on, every time I move an event or alter it's duration, the eventDataTransform function is triggered and all my events get a start and end value of `undefined`.
This is weird because a drag shouldn't trigger the eventDataTransform function at all.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/fullcalendar.min.css' />
<link href='css/scheduler.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='js/scheduler.min.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("init");
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        weekends: false,
        weekNumbers: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        slotLabelFormat: 'H:mm',
        nowIndicator: true,
        selectable: true,
        defaultDate: '2017-09-12',
        editable: true,
        eventConstraint: {start: "08:00:00", end: "16:00:00"},
        eventDataTransform: function (eventData){
            var ro = new Object();
            ro.start = eventData.myStartField;
            ro.end = eventData.myEndField;
            ro.title = eventData.myTitleField;
            ro.sourceObject = eventData;
            console.log("converted event", ro);
            return ro;
        },
        events: [
            {
                myTitleField: 'Long Event',
                myStartField: '2017-09-07',
                myEndField: '2017-09-10'
            },
            {
                myTitleField: 'Meeting',
                myStartField: '2017-09-12T10:30:00',
                myEndField: '2017-09-12T12:30:00'
            },
            {
                myTitleField: 'Lunch',
                myStartField: '2017-09-12T12:00:00'
            },
            {
                myTitleField: 'Meeting',
                myStartField: '2017-09-12T14:30:00'
            },
            {
                myTitleField: 'Happy Hour',
                myStartField: '2017-09-12T17:30:00'
            }
        ]
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="calendar" class="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share your whole fullCalendar code, and some sample event data from your JSON feed, then we have got a working example of the problem, please?

Comment: ok, I added the full code

Comment: "all my events get a start and end value of undefined". I don't see this happening exactly, but I agree there seems to be a problem. What I get when I run your example is that when dragging or resizing, eventDataTransform is triggered, and the first thing that gets passed into it is the object defined in `eventContstraint`. For each timeslot that I drag across, I see in the console: `converted event {"sourceObject":{"start":"08:00:00","end":"16:00:00"}}` and then a exception:

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined
    at P (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at V (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at O (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Yt.N [as buildEventFromInput] (fullcalendar.min.js:6)
    at Yt.De.constraintToEvents (fullcalendar.min.js:9)
    at Yt.De.isSpanAllowed (fullcalendar.min.js:9)
    at Yt.d.internalApiVersion.r.isSpanAllowed (scheduler.min.js:6)
    at Yt.De.isEventSpanAllowed (fullcalendar.min.js:9)
    at function.e.constructor.isEventLocationAllowed (fullcalendar.min.js:8)
    at constructor.hitOver (fullcalendar.min.js:7)`

Comment: I agree, I can't see why eventDataTransform needs to run, or why it would get the eventConstraint object passed into it. Perhaps there is a good reason for the callback to execute, but even if there is, it doesn't seem to work as intended. If I was you I would raise it as a bug - instructions here: https://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Reporting-Bugs/

Comment: FWIW, in my tests I found what @ADyson already reported - `eventDataTransform` is called every time you drag or edit an event, but the data it is passed is your `eventConstraint` object, not the event you are editing. The results logged to the console are therefore junk, but the event you dragged is still OK on the calendar - you can check it by logging its details in `eventDrop()`.  However for the life of me I can't get `eventConstraint` to work with `eventDataTransform()` - I can drag your events anywhere, no matter what I have in `eventConstraint`.

Comment: but the problem remains that there is no constraint what so ever. I filed a bug report on gitHub https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3859

Comment: @DanyDhondt I believe your bug report should also include two key pieces of information - 1) that despite the errors in the console, the dragging and resizing still works, and 2) that the eventConstraint specified does not work - i.e. it does not restrict the dragging / resizing to the time period given.

Comment: Ok, will do that!